# All special character codes are not converting to respective symbol with Domsanitizer

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-directive

I have Apostrophe (') code in the string Ex: "Test'Name", Using Domsanitizer I am sanitizing it to convert ' to Apostrophe symbol. But if I have double quotes code ("), it is not being converted to respective symbol. Not only for this, (&) is also not converting from code(&) to symbol. Below is the code I've written so far.

Am I doing correct thing regarding conversion, from code to symbol?

```
let txt = 'Test&#34;Name';
let txt2 = 'Test&#39;Name';
txt = this.sanitizer.sanitize( SecurityContext.HTML, txt );
txt2 = this.sanitizer.sanitize( SecurityContext.HTML, txt2 );

const ul = this.renderer.createElement('ul');
const li = this.renderer.createElement('li');
const li2 = this.renderer.createElement('li');
const text = this.renderer.createText(txt);
const text2 = this.renderer.createText(txt2);

this.renderer.appendChild(li, text);
this.renderer.appendChild(li2, text2);
this.renderer.appendChild(ul, li);
this.renderer.appendChild(ul, li2);
this.renderer.appendChild(this.el.nativeElement, ul);
```

Please find the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lbhl1x) here

**Issue 1:** Some codes are not being converted to respective symbols

**Issue 2:** If I have some french characters like é, then it is being converted to code, instead of showing the same (Updated the stackblitz too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case sanitizer converts value to use safely in browser DOM.

So you need to assign converted value to **innerHTML** (not to text nodes).

```ts
const ul = this.renderer.createElement('ul');
const li = this.renderer.createElement('li');
const li2 = this.renderer.createElement('li');
li.innerHTML = txt;   // <- inner html
li2.innerHTML = txt2; // <- inner html

this.renderer.appendChild(ul, li);
this.renderer.appendChild(ul, li2);
this.renderer.appendChild(this.el.nativeElement, ul);
```